# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}\right)$

Tags: limits, trigonometry, summation

So I was watching an "old" video from Numberphile, ["The Three Square Geometry Problem"](https://youtu.be/m5evLoL0xwg). Here is a screenshot:

[image]

It's pretty easy to see that the sum of three angles is 90°, but now I am curious: What if we keep going on? What if we had more than 3 squares and with that more than 3 angles? What would the sum be?

Basically I want to find the value of:
$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}\right)$$

If there is an answer I would like to know it.
Thank you.

P.S. $\arctan$ stands for $\tan^{-1}$

Comment: Please give a summary of the relevant information from the video in your post.  You can't expect people to watch a 12-minute youTube clip in order to understand your question.

Comment: As it relates to generalizing the three-square problem, it should really just be $1/k$ inside the arctan, not $1/\sqrt{k^2+1}$. (Note, there is a link to the question here from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800600/extended-3square-problem .)

Comment: The identity $\arctan\left(1\over x\right)={\pi\over2}-\arctan x$ prevents the sum from converging because the constant $\frac{\pi}{2}$ would be added INFINITE times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit does not exist.

Indeed, for $0\le x< \pi$ we have

\begin{align}
\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\le\sin(x)\le x
\end{align}

Since $\arctan$ is increasing for the appropriate range of values of $x$, we get:

$$
x\le\arctan (x)
$$

for all $x$.

Now we get, for all $k\ge 1$:
\begin{align}
\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}\right) & \ge\frac1{\sqrt{k^2+1}}\\
&\ge \frac1{\sqrt{k^2+3k^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2k}
\end{align}

Since the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$ [is known to diverge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), your series diverges too.

> [image]

Comment: One of the initial inequalities seems to be backwards: $x\le\tan x$ for $x\in[0,\frac\pi2)$.  This can be repaired, though: since arctan is concave on $[0,\infty)$, the secant over $[0,\frac1{\sqrt2}]$ lies under the graph; thus $\arctan x\ge cx$ with $c = \arctan(1/\sqrt2)/(1/\sqrt2)$.  The argument can then proceed as before, just with the extra $c$.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk Feel free to edit it so it's correct.